# Next JS production build not loading files

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I just built static production files for my next.js project.

In the development environment everything worked out great, but when I change to the production environment, the page exhibits lots of 404 messages saying it was unable to find any of the files inside _next folder:

[image]

That is curiously also the case when I open the file locally:

[image]

Basically the system is unable to find any of the _next files.
In the githubpages version the links are correct but throw 404 anyway...
In the local version the links clearly get corrupted...

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Can you link the GitHub repository

Comment: https://github.com/veigajoao/crypto-monkeys-game-page

Comment: Oh wait I'm a fool I could've gotten the repo from the github pages link lol

Comment: There you go  my friend!

Comment: Here is the [guide](https://wallis.dev/blog/deploying-a-next-js-app-to-github-pages) I used for my projects.

Comment: I was actually following the same guide, but none of the suggestions worked...

Comment: After removing "_" from all files names / url references the page is loading as expected, very weird though...